# DropdownButton Widget in flutter not accepting numbers in quotation

Tags: drop-down-menu, dart, flutter

I have this widget shown below that works as long as the items are letters but as soon as I switch them to numbers in single quotation marks, it stops working and gives me this error:

```
    I/flutter (31770): The following assertion was thrown 
    building ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(dirty):
    I/flutter (31770): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed 
    assertion: line 481 pos 15: 'value == null ||
    I/flutter (31770): items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value 
    == value).length == 1': is not true.
```

here is the actual widget:

```
      Widget _buildServingDropdownButton(Product product) {
if (product != null) {
  topperValue = product.topper;
}
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        title: const Text('Topper'),
        trailing: DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: Text('Choose'),
            onChanged: (String value) {
              setState(() {
                topperValue = value;

                print(topperValue);
              });
            },
            value: topperValue,
            items: <String>[
              '1',
            ].map((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList()),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: what is the type of "topperValue" and the type of "product.topper" ?

Comment: @diegoveloper topperValue is string and product.topper is string too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when the value specified is not available in your `DropdownMenuItem`.

You just defined one item :

```
items: <String>[
          '1',
        ]
```

But if your topperValue is different , you will get that error.

```
if (product != null) {
   topperValue = product.topper;  //different from '1' 
 }

value: topperValue,
```

Comment: That might be it but I'm not sure how it's not available since i declare it with an assigned value of '1' and i even removed the if statement, I'll have to look through my code and see where the value changes.